# Preservation of lax limits in categories of functors and lax natural transformations

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{D}$ be a functor of 2-categories and let $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathbb{C},\operatorname{Cat})^{\operatorname{lax}}$ denote the 2-category of functors and lax natural transformations.

Is it true in general that restriction along $f$,

$f^*:\operatorname{Fun}(\mathbb{D},\operatorname{Cat})^{\operatorname{lax}} \to \operatorname{Fun}(\mathbb{C},\operatorname{Cat})^{\operatorname{lax}}$

preserves all lax (weighted) limits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this functor preserves all *oplax* limits, and more generally all "$l$-rigged limits" in the sense of [Enhanced 2-categories and limits for lax morphisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2111) by Steve Lack and myself.  (I don't think it's reasonable to ask it to preserve *lax* limits, since these 2-categories don't in general even *have* lax limits.)

To prove this, using the technology of that paper, observe that $\mathrm{Fun}({C},\mathrm{Cat})^{\rm lax}$ is $T_{{C}}\rm Alg_l$ for a 2-monad $T_{{C}}$ on the 2-category $\mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{C}}$ of families of categories indexed by the objects of ${C}$.  This 2-category underlies an $\mathcal{F}$-category $T_C \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l$ for a corresponding $\mathcal{F}$-monad $T_{C}$ on $\mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{C}}$, which includes the data of the strict natural transformations as well and their embedding into the lax ones.

The main result of the above-cited paper is that the forgetful $\mathcal{F}$-functor $U_C:T_C \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l\to\mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{C}}$ creates $l$-rigged limits, so that $T_C \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l$ has these limits and $U_C$ preserves them.  These are a class of $\mathcal{F}$-enriched weighted limits which include "oplax limits whose generating projections are strict and detect strictness".  (Steve had already proven in [Limits for Lax Morphisms](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-005-2958-5) that oplax limits of this sort lift in the 2-categorical case.)

Now $f:C\to D$ induces a commutative square of $\mathcal{F}$-functors involving $U_C$ and $U_D$ and the restriction functors $f^*: \mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{D}} \to \mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{C}}$ and $f^* :T_D \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l \to T_C \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l$.  The former $f^*$ preserves all limits since they are pointwise, hence the composite $T_D \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l \to \mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{D}} \to \mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{C}}$ preserves $l$-rigged limits.  Therefore, so does the composite $T_D \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l \to T_C \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l\to \mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}{C}}$.  This means that the comparison maps for $l$-rigged limits induced by $f^* :T_D \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l \to T_C \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l$ are inverted by $U_D$.  But the forgetful $\mathcal{F}$-functor $U_D$ is conservative, so these comparison maps are already isomorphisms in $T_D \mathbb{A}\mathrm{lg}_l$, i.e. $f^*$ preserves $l$-rigged limits.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this argument depends crucially on the use of $\mathcal{F}$-categories (or something equivalent), since the forgetful 2-functor $T_C \mathrm{Alg}_l \to \mathrm{Cat}^{\mathrm{ob}C}$ is *not* conservative: a lax natural transformation can have invertible components without being itself invertible.  We need to know that the comparison maps are in fact *strict* natural transformations, and this requires knowing that the oplax limits are in fact $\mathcal{F}$-limits, i.e. their generating projections are strict and detect strictness.